# wx only execute on mouseover, not during GUI initialization

Tags: lambda, wxpython, wxwidgets, mouseover, functools

**Basic outline of situation**

In wxPython, I have a `wx.lib.sized_controls.SizedFrame()` as a class object which holds a `wx.lib.sized_controls.SizedScrolledPanel()` with `SetSizerProps(expand=True, proportion=9)` and `SetSizerType('grid', {'cols': 14, 'hgap': 1, 'vgap': 1})`.

So it is a self expanding and aligning grid-sizer based GUI, with scrollbars. It works perfectly.

**Current approach**

Inside the GUI, I build the contents one row at a time. Every row starts with a StaticText object displaying a "rank". When I hover the text with the mouse I want a popup window to be showed. I currently create it in a loop as such:

```
# Define and set rank
rank = wx.StaticText(self.sp, label=cdc.get_rank(result, result[7]))
rank.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.on_enter_field(conf.DATABASE_NAME_1, result[7], rank, "Rank", "Rank"))
rank.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, mm.on_mouse_leave())
```

This works, for when I hover the mouse over the wx.StaticText object in the GUI the self.on_enter_field() method is called and the popup window shows up correctly.

**Problem**

However, the problem is, when I create it in this way the `self.on_enter_field()` is called many times when the script is executed. For every row that is created in the GUI the method is initialized.

**Needed result**

What I want is that the on_enter_field() method is **only** initialized when the mouse hovers the wx.StaticText() field and **not** during GUI creation.

**Failed attempts**

I tried the following 2 approached, both failed because when I tried it in these ways the method wasn't initialized at all:

**Failed attempt 1 (with functools)**

```
import functools

# Define and set rank
rank = wx.StaticText(self.sp, label=cdc.get_rank(result, result[7]))
rank.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, functools.partial(self.on_enter_field, coin_id=result[7], field=rank, field_name="Rank", category="Rank"))
rank.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.on_mouse_leave)
```

**Failed attempt 2 (with lambda function)**

```
# Define and set rank
rank = wx.StaticText(self.sp, label=cdc.get_rank(result, result[7]))
rank.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, lambda event, field=rank: self.on_enter_field(event, result[7], field, "Rank", "Rank"))
rank.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.on_mouse_leave)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Do not use parentheses in the Bind method… use rank.Bind(event, method), not rank.Bind(event, method())

Comment: But how can I then pass variables to the method?

Comment: @Montmons You clearly already understand `instance` variables because you are using `self.sp`. If you declare the variable as `self.whatever`, you can access them in the function, without specifically passing them. Or use `lambda` as in  one of your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "Bind" the "Enter Window" and "Leave Window" events after the full initialisation of your frame and controls, when everything is shown.

Something like the following:

```
frame = MyFrame(......)
frame.Show()
frame.DoBindEvents()
......
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'GUISizedFrame' object has no attribute 'DoBindEvents'. 

The GUISizedFrame is a wx.lib.sized_controls.SizedFrame() object.

Comment: @Montmons, you need to use `Bind`. He just use `DoBindEvents()` to show you that all events should be use/bound at the very end of initialization. Otherwise what you are seeing will happen. You can't predict where the mouse is during the program start and whether the user will type some keys.

Comment: Or any other event will happen for that matter.